# Is it possible to export MySQL schema to XML?

Tags: mysql, xml

With MySQL I can:

- export **data** to XML
- export **data** and/or **schema** to SQL

But I can't export table **schema** to XML. Is there some sort of pre-built mechanism or do I have to make that manually (iterating thru "show tables" and then parsing "show columns for tablexxx" ?

EDIT: No tools wanted, just mysql syntax (must dynamically run from my server code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find such thing, so I assume no, it isn't. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in feature for mysql to do this but you can look at phpmyadmin it can do the export to xml.

Comment: No thanks, it must be dynamic from my code. I probably should have told that, let me edit quesiton.